# I'm getting error The argument type 'RemoteMessage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code of getrequestid it gives me error:

> The argument type RemoteMessage can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

so i need to convert remote message to map message

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging=FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  Future initialize(context) async {    
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
          (RemoteMessage message) {
            print("im clicked1");
      getRideRequestId(message);
      },
    );
  }



  Future getToken() async{
    String? token=await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print("This Your Token");
    print(token);
    driversRef.child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid).child("token").set(token);
    firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("alldrivers");
    firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("allusers");

  }

String getRideRequestId(Map<String,dynamic> message){
  String rideRequestId="";
  if(Platform.isAndroid){
    rideRequestId=message['data']['ride_request_id'];
    print("Print request id::");
    print(rideRequestId);
  }else{
   rideRequestId=message['ride_request_id'];
  }
  return rideRequestId;
}
```

Comment: is this what you want `getRideRequestId(message.data);`?

Comment: i tried but its giving me again error that tried requestid at null

Comment: can you show the output of `print(message.data);`?

Comment: E/flutter ( 7007): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7007): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7007): Tried calling: []("ride_request_id")

Comment: I believe it's possible the error is in this line_ `rideRequestId=message['data']['ride_request_id'];` but I am not sure

Comment: thanks for the help it resolved my issue by printing message.data i was getting [data][request_id] so i just removed [data] because message.data is already i have and again thanks for the help bro

Answer (score 0):

The data for a message is stored in its `data` property, so:

```
rideRequestId=message.data['ride_request_id'];
```

For problems like this I highly recommend keeping the reference documentation of the product handy, such as for [`RemoteMessage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage-class.html) in this case.